# Drop-down currency selector

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an eCommerce site and have included some code for adding a drop-down currency selector. However, although the currency physically changes, the top of the menu that should also update to display the name of the currently selected currency only displays the 'United Kingdom' default.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="currency">
<form method="post" action="/" name="lancur">
    <table class="tables">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="both"><b>Currency:</b></p>
                </td>
                <td><img src="/admin/images/flags/gb.gif" align="right" hspace="0" vspace="0" alt="Sterling (GBP)"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" width="100%" style="padding-top: 3px">
                    <select name="currency" style="width: 100%" onchange="lancur.submit();">
                        <option value="2">Euro (EUR)</option>
                        <option selected="" value="1">Sterling (GBP)</option>
                        <option value="3">US Dollar (USD)</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="text" class="conform" name="conform" value="">
</form>
<div class="current-currency"><span><i class="fa fa-gbp"></i> United Kingdom</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></div>
<ul style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
    <li><a href="?currency=1" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-gbp"></i> United Kingdom</a></li>
    <li><a href="?currency=2" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-eur"></i> Europe</a></li>
    <li><a href="?currency=3" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> United states</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script>
var current = $( ".currency select option:selected" ).val();
if (current==1){
  $( ".current-currency span" ).html('<i class="fa fa-gbp"></i> United Kingdom');
}
if (current==2){
  $( ".current-currency span" ).html('<i class="fa fa-eur"></i> Europe');
}
if (current==3){
  $( ".current-currency span" ).html('<i class="fa fa-usd"></i> United States');
}
$( ".current-currency" ).click(function() {
  $( ".currency ul" ).slideToggle("fast");
});
</script>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated - many thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: Add an on change event to `.currency select`, you not added any events so its not going to do anything on change.

Comment: Plus `lancur.submit();` will cause a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

As Lawrence states that, change the following HTML:

```
 <select name="currency" style="width: 100%" onchange="lancur.submit();">
```

to

```
 <select name="currency" style="width: 100%" onchange="updateName()">
```

And then add the following javascript code:

```
    function updateName() {
    var current = $(".currency select option:selected").val();
    if (current == 1) {
        $(".current-currency span").html('<i class="fa fa-gbp"></i> United Kingdom');
    }
    if (current == 2) {
        $(".current-currency span").html('<i class="fa fa-eur"></i> Europe');
    }
    if (current == 3) {
        $(".current-currency span").html('<i class="fa fa-usd"></i> United States');
    }
    $(".current-currency").click(function() {
        $(".currency ul").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your help it's very much appreciated, but unfortunately I have altered the code as per instructed and it is stopping the menu from dropping down.The code I obtained was from this site that is on the same eCommerce platform that I am: www.thediscdjstore.com - look at the very top-right. Thanks again.